# Any good Python HTTP proxies?

Tags: python, http, testing, proxy, automation

There [is a long list of python http proxies.](http://proxies.xhaus.com/python/) Does anyone have experience with them and have any recommendations? I need to run a proxy for automation tests running on a windows machine in IE. I want a proxy that has an API for monitoring traffic, so I can give go signals to the automation tests when a page appears to have stopped making requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list seems to be quite old. I would have a look at Twisted. According to [this documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.web.proxy.Proxy.html) there's something available.

Comment: Wow much better than the other Python http proxies I have been working with. And they actually have documentation!